# Cannot access RDS MySQL after assigning secondary private IP address to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, static-ip-address

The instances are set up on a common VPC as follows:

- EC2 instance running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on a public subnet
- RDS MySQL on a private subnet
- Both EC2 and RDS on common security group allowing inbound traffic on port 3306

**The connection works fine when on the primary private IP address.**

After assigning a secondary private IP address to the EC2 instance, I perform the following:

- Add the static IP to the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg` file:

  Default file content:

  `auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback`

  `auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp`

  Add static IP address:

  `auto eth0:0
   iface eth0:0 inet static
   address xx.xx.xx.xx`
- Run `sudo ifup eth0:0`

After this, MySQL refuses the connection and returns this error message:

> Cannot access the database: No route to host *(DNS_OF_RDS)*

The connection is re-established when I run `sudo ifdown eth0:0`.

What am I missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by adding the netmask address (`netmask 255.255.xx.xx`) at end of the file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg`.